# Inertia group representation from $p^{n}$-torsion of ordinary elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Let $K$ be a complete local field. Suppose that $K$ is an unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ and let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $K$ with good ordinary reduction. Let     $G_{K}=\text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)$ be the Galois group and $I_{K}=\text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K^{nr})$ be the inertia group where $K^{nr}$ is the maximal unramified extension of $K$.

As $E$ is ordinary, we have the following short exact sequence of $I_{K}$-modules:

$$0 \rightarrow \mu_{p} \hookrightarrow E[p] \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0 $$

This gives a representation of the inertia group:

$$\rho_{1}:I_{K} \rightarrow \text{Aut}(E[p]) \cong \text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) $$

In Serre's paper (Prop. 11):

https://www.wstein.org/sage_summer/bsd_comp/Serre-properties_galoisiennes_des_points_dordre_fini_des_courbes_elliptiques.pdf

He states that the inertia group $I_{K}$ acts on $E[p]$ by matrices of the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\chi_{p} & *\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\chi_{p}:I_{K}\rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ is the cyclotomic character. Then the image of $I_{K}$ in $\text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is either a group of order $p-1$ or $p(p-1)$ (these are the only possible subgroups consisting only of these matrices).

I would like to know what can be said about the inertia group action on $p^{n}$-torsion for all $n\geq 1$:

(I believe) we still have an exact sequence:

$$0 \rightarrow \mu_{p^{n}} \hookrightarrow E[p^{n}] \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0 $$

And that the induced representation: $\rho_{n}:I_{K}\rightarrow \text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z})$ still consists of matrices of the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\chi_{p^{n}} & *\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
I would like to know the possibilities for $\rho_{n}(I_{K})$.

In Kraus's paper (IV Appendix):
https://eudml.org/doc/270073

He states that if $\lambda$ is the Serre-Tate parameter of $E$, then the above sequence is split for $n\geq 1$ if and only if $\lambda$ is a $p^{n}$-th power.

I am more interested in the non-split case, and in particular, is there a lower bound on the cardinality of the image: $\rho_{n}(I_{K})\leq \text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z})$? Or is every possible upper triangular subgroup that contains the matrices:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\chi_{p^{n}} & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
a possibility?

Comment: Remarque 2 in the paper by Kraus indicates that you should look for the canonical lift of an ordinary elliptic curve over a finite field.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich My understanding is that if $\tilde{E}$ is the reduction mod $p$ of $E$, then the canonical lifting of $\tilde{E}$ is the elliptic curve $E_{can}$ over $K$ with special fibre isomorphic to $\tilde{E}$ and split $p^{n}$-torsion for all $n\geq 1$. I am more interested in the 'generic' case where the $p^{n}$-torsion is not split, and what the possibilities for the inertia group action are in these cases.